# Java ¿Deseas continuar sin guardar?

Tags: java

quiero realizar que cuando hayan cambios en la Tabla y el botón de Guardar encendido muestre: ¿Deseas continuar sin guardar la información? al presionar cualquiera de JComboBox que hay, en este caso son dos JComboBox que son: Años y Secciones

Intente hacer un mouseReleased a los JComboxBox para que detecte si el botón de Guardar si esta encendido, muestre el mensaje, pero no funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    private void comboSeccionesMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                             
        
        if (Save.isEnabled() == true) {
            int confirmSave = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane,
                    "¿Deseas cambiar de Sección sin haber guardado la información reciente?",
                    "Guardar",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            
            if (confirmSave == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                Save.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes utilizar el evento `ItemListener` que se llama siempre que ocurre un cambio en el JComboBox. En este caso, aparecerá el dialog para confirmar cuando se seleccione un elemento diferente al que esta seleccionado.

```
comboSecciones.addItemListener(e -> {
    if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
        if (Save.isEnabled() == true) {
            int confirmSave = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane,
                    "¿Deseas cambiar de Sección sin haber guardado la información reciente?",
                    "Guardar",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            
            if (confirmSave == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                Save.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Esto tiene un problema y es que si se presiona "No", el item del JComboBox cambiará de todas formas debido a que el evento de escucha ocurre cuando se cambia, lo que significaría que el programa debería cambiar de sección por mas que se halla presionado "No".

Para solucionarlo deberías cambiar ligeramente el mensaje que aparece en el dialogo por algo así:

```
¿Deseas guardar la información reciente antes de cambiar de sección?
```

En este caso el elemento del JComboBox cambiará de todas formas, pero si se presiona "Si" guardarías los cambios y si "No" los descartarías y el elemento cambiaría como normalmente lo hace.

Eso te evitaría las confusiones del por que al presionar "No" el item cambia.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la orientación, y por explicarme cada detalle del funcionamiento.